# No Web Application Option in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, vs-web-application-project

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2.3. When I'm trying to create a new project, web application option is not available. I have already enabled all the Java EE plugins including JPA, EJB, Servlets. However, web application is still not there. I have attached my screenshots below. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you!

Sorry for my low reputation, not be able to insert images in my post, please see the links this website created.
[Trying to create a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sskDQ.png)
[Java ee plugins all enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLUBB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE Web application type structure and dependencies are created if any of web frameworks present (JAX-RS, JAX-WS, etc) or Web Profile checked. For example for a simple JSP application that you would run on Tomcat select `Servlet` option:

[image]

See also [Tutorial: Your first Java EE application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html).

Comment: Got it! Thank you for saving a newbie's life!